# Do Cat Shines collected while Fury Bowser isn’t attacking deal damage?

Tags: bowsers-fury

In *Bowser’s Fury*, collecting a Cat Shine while Fury Bowser is attacking will lower his health for when you fight him later as giant Cat Mario.

If I collect a Cat Shine while Fury Bowser isn’t attacking, will it deal damage to him? Or are Cat Shines only effective if I wait for Bowser to start attacking first?

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect the Cat Shine while Fury Bowser is awake, or it won't damage him. Note that you can summon Fury Bowser at any time by tapping a bowser amiibo.